# Normalization of float point when checking if the number is "harmonic divisor number (Ore number)"

Tags: floating-point, exponent, normalize, mantissa

My function isOre is checking if the number is "harmonic divisor number (Ore number)" or not
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_divisor_number#CITEREFCohenSorli2010).
I can not rightfully compare if the "result variable" is integer number because the part of it is inside exponent. (https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

My question is:
1. How can I solve it?
2. Are there alternative solutions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isOre(unsigned int n){
double numbersSum = 0;
int number = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
    if (n % i == 0){
        numbersSum += (double)1 / i ;
        //cout << "numbersSum " << numbersSum << endl;
        ++number;
        //cout << "number " << number << endl;

    }
}

double result = number / numbersSum;
int result1 = result;


cout << "       " << result << "        " << result1 << "       ";
if (result == result1) return true;
else return false;
}

int main() { 
//Test sequence of Ore numbers from https://oeis.org/A001599
int array[34] = {1, 6, 28, 140, 270, 496, 672, 1638, 2970, 6200, 8128,
8190, 18600, 18620, 27846, 30240, 32760, 55860, 105664, 117800, 167400,
173600, 237510, 242060, 332640, 360360, 539400, 695520, 726180, 753480, 950976,
1089270, 1421280, 1539720};

cout << "array[i]" << " " << "double" << "  " << "toInt" << "   " << "Result" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 34; ++i){
cout << array[i];
cout << isOre(array[i]) << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

In main I have my testcase sequence that must pass.

My Output:

array[i]    double  toInt   Result

1       1       1       1

6       2       2       1

28      3       3       1

140     5       5       1

270     6       6       1

496     5       5       1

672     8       8       0

1638        9       9       0

2970        11      11      0

6200        10      10      1

8128        7       7       1

8190        15      15      0

18600       15      15      0

18620       14      14      0

27846       17      17      0

30240       24      23      0

32760       24      24      0

55860       21      21      0

105664      13      13      0

117800      19      19      0

167400      27      27      0

173600      25      25      0

237510      29      29      0

242060      26      26      0

332640      44      43      0

360360      44      43      0

539400      29      29      1

695520      46      46      0

726180      39      39      0

753480      46      45      0

950976      27      27      0

1089270     42      42      0

1421280     47      46      0

1539720     47      46      0

P.S. It is not relevant but I will be very thankful if somebody can point out why do I have shift in my output after line that starts with 672.

Links to the materials corresponding the problem.

http://planetmath.org/OreNumber;

http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1):

As the page you reference notes, the harmonic mean of the divisors of n can be expressed as *n*•σ<sub>0</sub>(*n*) / σ<sub>1</sub>(*n*), where σ<sub>0</sub>(*n*) is the number of divisors and σ<sub>1</sub>(*n*) is the sum of the divisors. So simply calculate the numerator and the denominator with integer arithmetic and then test whether the remainder of the division would be zero.

Note that the arithmetic will break down for large numbers, so your program must test for this and either stop when it cannot continue or must use alternate arithmetic methods to support large numbers. This is true of either integer or floating-point arithmetic. However, if you are iterating through candidates one by one and using 64-bit integer arithmetic, you will not reach the point where overflow is a problem.